# Echo variable of different page in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP how do I change the variable of a different page.

For example:

header.php

```
// For style-specific pages.
echo $header_styles;
```

Then in a page like, index.php:

```
include('header.php');
echo $header_styles = "<style></style>";
```

I used to know how to do this, but I completely forgot.

Comment: You're changing it after you're `echo`ing it?

Comment: Remove the echo in your index.html (which should be index.php, and open with an <?php tag), and place it before your include.

Comment: If I understood it right, you want the access to `$header_styles` on a page and then overwrite/change it later? Also, you won't be able to use PHP code inside .html pages

Comment: Yes, I want to overwrite the variable so that anytime I include header.php on a page, I can echo the variable and it will include whatever I want. Kind of like having a dynamic title of a page.

Comment: Ok, let me edit the "index.html". It was a typo. I meant index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do that first:

In your header.php you will have:

```
<?php
echo $header_styles;
?>
```

Then in a page that you need to include the header, like index.php you will have:

```
<?php
    $header_styles = "<style></style>";
    include('header.php');
?>
<html>
   Your html code here
</html>
```

You need to change the name from index.html to index.php. Then you need to set the variable before to call header.php and then you will do the "echo" to that.
Do not apply the echo when you are setting the value, because I think you do not want to print that you need only to set the value.